# How to create player with command "mobileControlCreate" in group? - Livecode

Tags: livecode

I want to create the player in group on mobile.

I use this command "mobileControlCreate" for create player.

Here my code:

```
   mobileControlCreate "player", "videoControl"
   mobileControlSet "videoControl", "filename", specialFolderPath("engine") & "/vdo.mp4"
   mobileControlSet "videoControl", "preserveAspect", true
   mobileControlSet "videoControl", "showController", true
   mobileControlSet "videoControl", "visible", true
   mobileControlSet "videoControl", "rect", the rect of grp "o_c2"
```

How do I do?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Perhaps we can find a different solution to achieve the same effect.

Comment: I create image in group and input fuction swipe in group like slideshow.When I swipe right or left.I want to the player move follow me.I'm not good english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mobileControlCreate` to create a player, as you currently do. Now use `mobileControlCreate` to create a scroller.

```
local lMovieScrollerID // declare outside handler

on createScroller
  mobileControlCreate "scroller","Movie Scroller"
  put the result into lMovieScrollerID
  mobileControlSet lMovieScrollerID,"rect",the rect of this cd
  put the rect of this cd into myRect
  put item 3 of myRect * 2 into item 3 of myRect
  put item 4 of myRect * 2 into item 4 of myRect
  mobileControlSet lMovieScrollerID,"contentRect",myRect
end createScroller
```

The createScroller handler creates a scroller that can scroll over an area that is 4 times as large as your card. Therefore, you can scroll your movie exactly off screen. You will need to experiment to find out what kinf of rect (the value of myRect) you actually need.

In the next handler, let's assume that the rect of your group is 100,100,200,200.

```
on scrollerDidScroll theScrollH,theScrollV
  put "100,100,200,200" into myInitialRect
  add theScrollH to item 1 of myInitialRect
  add theScrollH to item 3of myInitialRect
  add theScrollV to item 2 of myInitialRect
  add theScrollV to item 4 of myInitialRect
  // obviously myInitialRect is no longer "initial" here
  set the rect of grp "o_c2" to myInitialRect
  mobileControlSet lMovieScrollerID,"rect",myInitialRect
end scrollerDidScroll
```

It should be clear that these handlers are untested and need some experimentation, but I am pretty sure that this is the path you'll have to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Native controls float above the stack and are not part of the card, so - unfortunately - you can't place them in a group.